# ValueError when using a variable to call a function

Tags: python, variables, nltk

I am trying to write a simple script that starts with a word and then keeps printing words that rhyme with the one before it (i.e. egg, aaberg, mpeg). It uses NLTK. However whilst running the code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\myname\Google Drive\Python codes\Rhyming words.py", line 58, in <module>
     word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]
   File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 242, in randint
     return self.randrange(a, b+1)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 218, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)

ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0,0)
```

I have narrowed it down to one function, the main one, that returns a list of words that rhyme.

```
def rhyme(inp, level):
     entries = nltk.corpus.cmudict.entries()
     syllables = [(word, syl) for word, syl in entries if word == inp]
     rhymes = []
     for (word, syllable) in syllables:
             rhymes += [word for word, pron in entries if pron[-level:] == syllable[-level:]]
     return rhymes
```

When I do rhyme("egg", 1) it returns with a list of rhyming words. No problem right? But then if i do:

```
x = "egg"
rhyme(x, 1)
```

I get the error stated above. To paraphrase, it throws an error when I use a variable and I really don't know why.

Full code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import nltk, time, os
from random import randint

###Words###

import urllib2

word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"

response = urllib2.urlopen(word_site)
txt = response.read()
WORDS = txt.splitlines()

###end WORDS###

def rhyme(inp, level):
     entries = nltk.corpus.cmudict.entries()
     syllables = [(word, syl) for word, syl in entries if word == inp]
     rhymes = []
     for (word, syllable) in syllables:
             rhymes += [word for word, pron in entries if pron[-level:] == syllable[-level:]]
     return rhymes

def text_file(mode):
     if os.path.isfile("words.txt"):
          words = open("words.txt", mode)
     else:
          words = open("words.txt", "w")
     return words

def start_word():
     words = text_file("r")
     if open("words.txt", "r").readlines() == 0:
          return WORDS[randint(0, len(WORDS)-1)]
     else:
          word = words.readlines()[len(words.readlines())-1]
          return word[0:len(word)-2]
     words.close()

def last_word(last_word):
     words = text_file("a")
     words.write(last_word+"\n")
     words.close()



word_start = start_word()

#debug
print word_start, type(word_start)

while True:
     word = rhyme(word_start, 1)
     #debug
     print word

     if (len(word)-1) < 1:
          word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]

          print word_real
          last_word(word_real)
          word_start = word_real

          time.sleep(0.3)
```

All that was wrong was a < instead of a > in:

```
 if (len(word)-1) < 1:
          word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]
```

Comment: Please show the part of the code that has `word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)] `

Comment: I edited it to show the full code

Comment: Instead of `WORDS[randint(0, len(WORDS)-1)]` you could just do `random.choice(WORDS)`, but this, too, will fail if `WORDS` is empty.

Comment: `if (len(word)-1) < 1:` did you mean `> 1`? Otherwise this will _always_ fail!

Comment: that is a better solution although not the one to the problem...

Comment: I do not see any relation at all between the error and whether you use string literal `"egg"` or `x` containing the string. I suspect your analysis was wrong in this respect.

Comment: Neither do I, but that's the only thing that could be the cause

Comment: In my opinion that's the only thing that has exactly zero relation to the issue.

Comment: Isn't `randint(..., len(words)-1)` a typical off-by-one? Why would one subtract one from the length?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda That's not an "off by one". `randint` is inclusive.

Comment: @tobias_k: I was thinking in terms of python ranges, sorry.

Comment: `if (len(word)-1) > 1:` basically means `if len(word) > 2` just in unnecessarily complicated language...

Comment: `if open("words.txt", "r").readlines() == 0:` looks entirely wrong as well

Comment: You'd better rewrite the code to avoid `randint()` entirely as well as to avoid the other nonsense, code duplication, and unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating an empty range here:

```
if len(word)-1) < 1:
   word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]
```

so only if you have *zero or one elements in `word`* do you call `randint()`. The second argument then will be `0` or `-1`, and `randint(0, -1)` is invalid for that function.

You probably meant to use `>= 1` instead. Rather than use `randint()`, use `random.choice()` to pick a random element from a list:

```
if word:
   word_real = random.choice(word)
```

`if word` is true if the `word` list is not empty.

Comment: The cited code looks entirely wrong anyway. The `random.choice()` looks like what was intended.

Answer (score 1):

This does not have anything to do with using variables or not. The problem seems to be here:

```
 if (len(word)-1) < 1:
      word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]
```

You execute this part of code *only when* `len(word)-1) < 1`, i.e. you do `randint(0, 0)`!

You probably just mistakenly used `<` instead of `>`.

```
 if (len(word)-1) > 1:
      word_real = word[randint(0, len(word)-1)]
```

Or shorter:

```
 if word:
      word_real = random.choice(word)
```

Comment: well that stopped the error but not rhyme(word, level) coming out empty... one step at a time i guess

Comment: @iwishiwasaneagle: 
Time to amend the question with new code then.

Comment: Done that! Now to figure out why rhyme(word, level) returns empty when I use a variable! Wooooo....

Comment: @iwishiwasaneagle You should not alter the original code in your question. Now the answers might appear pointless. Instead, maybe just point out what exactly is wrong, probably with example input, i.e.: What is the value of `word` and `level`?

Comment: @tobias_k: Sorry that was my idea. In my opinion the question is entirely pointless to anyone out there and it's more of a code review than a question. Maybe we should just help him get on the right track and then delete it.